# Conditional Yup validation according to state variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

Is it possible to conditionally validate a text field using Yup resolver RHF, only when the state of a given variable is true.

I researched a lot but couldn't find an example.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. Which kind of condition

Comment: @Asifvora I have a state variable consisting of boolean value, the validation should be done only if the state is true

Comment: Both fields are different? Example: If checkbox true then apply validation on InputBox.

Answer (score 5):

To use `Yup.when` for archiving condition base validation.
Check more details [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup)

**Example:**

You can use Yup conditions

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  isCompany: Yup.boolean(),
  companyName: Yup.string().when('isCompany', {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string().required('Field is required')
  }),
  companyAddress: Yup.string().when('isCompany', {
    is: (isCompany) => true,//just an e.g. you can return a function
    then: Yup.string().required('Field is required'),
    otherwise: Yup.string()
  }),
});
```

And make sure to update your form accordingly. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Ok but there you are just comparing against the 'isCompany' value, which is a field named 'isCompany', isn't it?

Op (and so do I) wanted to know whether or not it was possible to compare against state variables instead

Comment: You mean `isCompany` name is `xyz`, or `ABC`? Something like this?

Comment: No, I mean to compare against a React state variable. like, lets say i have the state:
`const [isVerified, setIsVerified]` 
and I want a to be valid, or not, depending on the value of the isVerified state, that might be set to true according to the response of an api call, pe.

Comment: For that first, you need to set that value in formik field and based on that you can handle the conditional validations.